# Jquery : drop down menu causes page to jump to the top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a drop down menu on the 'more' link, but if you are scrolled down in the page at all when you click the fixed position menu 'more' the page jumps automaticaly to the top. Why is this? And can i change this? Thanks a lot

http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/61/

Edit: I've change the link from href="#" to href="www.google.com" because I'd like for a link to be there incase js does not load. Also adding return false cause all my links inside the ul to break. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're not going to put an actual url in the href, you can just as well use any other element, like a span.

Comment: thanks I will now put a url in there incase there is no jquery support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `href="#"` part from the link, that's what causes it and it's not needed as you've already got the onClick event.

Comment: Don't remove the href. It's a required attribute.

Comment: False. href is optional. Seems like you have never used anchors as navigation items :)

Comment: In that case you can just use a span. But most commonly, an `a` is used because it actually links to a useful page in case the client doesn't support the fancy menu. Downvoting this. AlienWebguy provided the correct answer.

Comment: @Alfabravo Seems you are correct sir: `Authors may also create an A element that specifies no anchors, i.e., that doesn't specify href, name, or id. Values for these attributes may be set at a later time through scripts.` via http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html

Comment: @GolezTrol A span is a span and has a meaning in an html document, an anchor is an anchor and it does not need to link to a useful page :) Please check the specs as AlienWebguy did. Nice question, though!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, add `event.preventDefault();` after `event.stopPropagation();`

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/rKaPN/52/

**EDIT:**

Per your comment, if you want to mix non-links with url-links in your nav, just give the active links a `class="link"`. Then in your code, you'd use a condition to prevent the default event:

```
  if($(this).hasClass('link')){
      window.location = $(this).attr('href');
  }
  else {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: Hi this was looking really nice but it actually makes the links inside my drop down menu not work, any ideas?

Comment: You should capture those links' click events earlier and do a `window.location` redirect OR change your navigation to not use the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I was liking the idea of the <a> tag to link to redirect if js is not enabled..could you elaborate on the window.location in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on RobinJ's answer:

The reason it jumps to the top here is that the hash is used for on page anchoring. That means locating the view at a particularly anchor's name. If you use a hash with no referenced anchor name, by default the screen will anchor to the top of the page.

When using javascript on anchors for actions that don't involve moving the screen or requesting a new URL, you generally won't need to enter an href attribute at all. A lot of people seem to think `<a>` requires this, but it really doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on RobinJ's answer:

The reason it jumps to the top here is that the hash is used for on page anchoring. That means locating the view at a particularly anchor's name. If you use a hash with no referenced anchor name, by default the screen will anchor to the top of the page.

There are ways around this, but I personally skip adding the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The page jumps, because the link is redirecting you to "#", you can add a `return false;` as the last statement of the code that handles the onclick event..., that should fix your problem.

Comment: doing this causes the links inside the .menu ul li ul to not work

Comment: If you press the link in order to show you the menu, then you don't want the link to work.

Answer (score 0):

for onclick events you can return value such as onclick="return someFunction()"

If someFunction returns a value of false it won't follow the link.

In this case it would ignore the #. If you had a URL there, it would likewise ignore that.

In your case since you're binding with jquery you can return false at the end of the function:

```
menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function (event) {
...
return false;
}
```

The method event.preventDefault() will also do this but it's good to know that you can return false to have a browser stop an event.

Comment: hi, adding this causes my links to not work inside my drop down menu, any ideas?

Comment: If you read my explanation, you'll see the answer to that but thanks for the downvote.

Comment: thanks, I didn't actually down vote you I can't down vote until I have 125 rep points.

Comment: Ok sorry. Well, you'll need return false only when the item containing a dropdown is clicked. so instead of returning false at the end of the find, return false at the end of the if statement where you check to see if it's toggling a dropdown. In other cases you don't need to return anything, or you can return true.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `href="#"` with `href="javascript:void(0);"`.

Comment: Never put javascript inside the href-attribute! That's what onClick is meant for!

Comment: because keeping the ui/display code separate from the event code is a better pattern to follow as it makes for easier maintenance, etc going forward.  +1 for asking "why not"